# Will ViewPagerAdapter not get called if no tabs are added to tab layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement TabLayout with View pager.
There is one condition where i dont want tablyout and just return a fragment,I am returning fragment from getItem() method of ViewPagerAdapter.
But this method is not getting called if no tabs are added to tab layout.

Comment: But thats by design. Its not really reasonable to call it when there is nothing to call.

Comment: How to return that fragment ,if getItem is not getting called,I want to attach single fragment to view pager and make the visibility of tablyout gone

Answer (score 0):

Will ViewPagerAdapter not get called if no tabs are added to tab layout?

***It will get called even if your not interested to add tabs to tablayout***

1. Make sure you have added Fragments to your Adapter list

   ```
     private void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
           ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
           adapter.addFrag(new PHRsplitActivity(),"one");
           adapter.addFrag(new EHRListActivity(),"two");
           adapter.addFrag(new LabReportsActivity(),"three");
           adapter.addFrag(new CalculatorListFragment(),"four");
           viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   ```

   2. Make sure Adapter is implemented correctly and Fragments are added to FragmentList.

```js
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Still you have problem let me know

Comment: Thanks,It helped me a lot

Comment: If it is right answer please upvote thanks in advance